# Sci-Fi movie with 3 boys and an alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

This sci-fi movie is about 3 friends (boys) who are also neighbors. But then the city wants to put an overpass above their homes, and so they have to move.

I do not remember most parts of this. They go on an adventure on their bikes to make the most out of the limited time they have left; they get this weird virus of their phone, which leads them to an alien. And then in the end they move...

P.S. Not *E.T.* or *Earth to Echo*

Comment: Was the phone that had the “virus” a land line or was it a mobile phone?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: You could start by telling us about the ages of the three boys, what the alien looked like, when you saw the film, what age-group it was aimed at, what 'adventures' they have on the way, etc etc

Comment: For the record, the film you're describing *is* Earth to Echo. "*After a construction project begins in their neighborhood, best friends Tuck (Brian "Astro" Bradley), Alex (Teo Halm) and Munch (Reese C. Hartwig) begin receiving strange, encoded messages on their cell phones. They immediately inform their parents and the authorities, but when no one takes them seriously, the youths decide to crack the code themselves and trace the messages to their source. The youths' curiosity leads them to a robotic extraterrestrial who desperately needs their help."*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like *Explorers* to me. But I don't remember anything about a phone or them having to move at the end.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain why do you think that "Explorer" is the right answer,

Comment: I don't think so.  Explorers is about three boys, but there was nothing about moving, and multiple aliens.  Explorers is about three boys who have dreams of a circuit board.  When they end up building it, it creates a forcefield.  They build a vessel out of a tilt-a-whirl car, and end up flying it around.  They fly into space, meet the aliens who sent the dreams, and then return to Earth.